# Mini Cooper 1.6 Diesel Carbon Coming From The Exhaust

Tags: diesel, exhaust, mini-cooper

I have just recently bought the car and have noticed that the car kicks out black smoke when I am driving, this only happens once or twice, but there is a lot of carbon inside the exhaust and also the back of the car gets filthy? Is there any easy fix without taking it back to the garage as I live an hour and a half away? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to pottering around town then accelerating causing the turbo to kick in - which then cleans all the carbon soot out... diesels with a turbo are known for it .

Comment: ok thanks for that, would I benefit from getting a Terraclean guy out to do a clean? Or would it be best to give it a drive down the motorway every now and again?

Comment: The second - otherwise known as an italian service. As for terraclean : search some of the forums for opinions vary from snake oil to bettrr than a desler....